What are the Zoho SDKs for Java?
I have been wrecking my brain for a couple of days and can't seem to figure it out. I got the CRM SDK to work, however, it doesn't have the functions I need.
I need to access Invoices and Invoice payments, is there a specific SDK for invoices? All searches I do either give me CRM or Analytics.

CRM SDK is just a wrapper that implements the proxy pattern and calls the HTTP API of the CRM. sometimes the SDK does not cover all API functions. but there is always the option to implement your own HTTP client that directly calls the REST API.
